# Tablewidget selecteditems in custom format

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a tablewidget in `PYQT5` in which i am clicking the row, to get the data out of row we have a builtin method

```
 self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.itemsinlist)
```

from which i am printing out `item.text()`using below function

```
 def itemsinlist(self):
     for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
         print (item.text())
```

but i am not able to get the data out in custom format i am getting 2 lines of data when i click John from the rows like below

**Ui Image**

[image]

**Console Output:**

[image]

How can i customise this data to my liking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try :

```
 def itemsinlist(self):
     items = self.tableWidget.selectedItems()
     data = " ".join(item.text() for item in items)
     print (data)
```

Result:

John 03/29/2010

Comment: is there a way i can get John and 03/29/2010 separately? instead of John 03/29/2010

Comment: I got it, i can use split method to split them..thanks again